# Finger Scanner not working in Android

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api

I am new to android application development.
I want to know from which API finger scanner support? Now I want to develop an app  which include finger scanner. Testing on LeTv device and it would crash at KeyGuard Manager class.

Comment: Shirish: this is considered [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for SO. If you have tried something, post your code and SO users may be able to help with the challenge.

Comment: Can you provide the log and the code you have used?

Comment: These as been added in API 23 (M) as you can see in the upper right corner : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.html

Answer (score 0):

I want to know what is the minimum requirement for applying finger scanner for android application development.